# push a job into laravel redis queue from another Laravel instance on same server?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue

I have two Laravel projects running on the same server.

The first calls second's api over HTTP, the the second pushes a job to notify some users.

As both projects live on the same server, can't i make the first project push the job to the second one's redis job queue?

Comment: You can do what you want, in fact, if you would have a "frontend" laravel server (just serving assets/blades), a "backend" laravel server (just handling API calls, just that) and a third laravel server, this third one would be just a queue handler server. When you use this approach, generally you have 2 or more "backend" servers and 2 or more "queue" servers (they will be told what queues to handle), so how do you communicate data between the same type of between them. In the case of queues/redis, just use the same connection and that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried this approach but it should be possible

You didn't specify what queue connections are your projects using, but let's assume that they use 2 different connections, for example 2 different redis servers

In your first laravel project `config/queue.php` add new connection to `connections` that will point to the queue connection of the second laravel project. Let's name it `project-2-connection`

Then you can use [dispatching to a particular connection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#dispatching-to-a-particular-connection)

```php
ExampleJob::dispatch($data)->onConnection('project-2-connection');
```

It's important to make sure that the same job class `ExampleJob` exists in both projects

To make your life easier you should pass `$data` as simple array and avoid `SerializesModels`. If you pass model from project 1 that doesn't exist in project 2 then [your job will will fail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#ignoring-missing-models) with a `ModelNotFoundException`. You could use models but then you would need to have same model in both projects

Answer (score 1):

Set-up a queue management server and this can receive of point your jobs into queues from even multiple servers. A simple code which might help is below;

```js
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Jobs\ProcessPodcast;
use App\Models\Podcast;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
class PodcastController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new podcast.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $podcast = Podcast::create(/* ... */);
 
        // Create podcast...
 
        ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->onQueue('processing');
    }
}
```